# AWS connect change password for agent permission

Tags: amazon-connect

Is there any way to provide change password option to agents, may be somewhere in the settings?

Currently I don't see that enable/disable permission option available for the agents.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the AWS connect only option we have is forgot password and same can be used for resetting password too, following are the steps for that

Reset your agent or manager password
Use the following steps if you want to change your password, or if you forgot it and need a new one.

> 1. If you're an Amazon Connect agent or manager, at the login page,
>    choose Forgot Password.
> 2. Type the characters you see in the image, and then choose Recover
>    Password.
> 3. A message will be sent to your email address with a link that you can
>    use to reset your password.

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/password-reset.html